# Issues with Beautiful Soup XML Parsing in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have this xml file which I wish to parse.
This is the code I have written. However it seems that it is unable to parse the file since it outputs none.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f=open("1.txt",'r')
y=BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml-xml")
print(y.url)
```

Output

```
None
```

Comment: What does `y` print?

Comment: Why did `y.url`?

Comment: hmmm I'm not extremely good with BeautifulSoup but try changing `open("1.txt",'r')` to `open("1.txt",'r').read()` really hope this will do the trick.

Comment: I have a 'url' tag in the document. <url>something<\url>

Comment: Adding .read() worked. but now it seems to be reading the first tag only. It ignores all the other.

Comment: Well that's great,I think I got the second part give me a sec I will post it as an answer

Comment: Why don't you use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is occurring due to the way that you are currently trying to open the file, so try replacing `f=open("1.txt",'r')` with `f=open("1.txt",'r').read()`.

also I would recommend you to change `print(y.url)` to `print(y.find_all('url'))`.
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse the XML data

## Sample XML File

```
<root_element>
    <url>This is my URL</url>
    <url>This is my 2nd URL</url>
</root_element>
```

## Python Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
path = r"Full_Path of your xml file"
tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()
url=root.findall('url')
url[0].text
url[1].text
```

## Output

'This is my URL'
'This is my 2nd URL'